# Which method is invoked after navigating back from a page in metro-style apps?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In metro Apps,
To navigate from pageA to pageB `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(pageB))`is used in pageA, and to navigate back `this.Frame.GoBack()` is used in pageB.

Which method of pageA will be invoked first once the user return from pageB?

I am looking for something like `onActivityResult` as in android.

Comment: Might be useful to say why you would like to know this in your question

Comment: @TheoKouzelis user input is taken in pageB and accordingly UI of pageA is changed. so, as soon as app navigates back from pageB, updateUI() in pageA needs to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the answers more colorful - the constructor is what will be called first when pageA has the default `NavigationCacheMode` of `Disabled`, but it might/will not be called at all in other cases and it might actually be worth setting it to something NavigationCacheMode at least temporarily to `Enabled` if you expect to quickly return to that page.

The more sure bet is to handle [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto.aspx) and take a navigation parameter object from there. Just make sure you don't pass anything more complicated than a short string or one of the other basic types (byte, Int16, Uint16, Int32/int, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, Single/float, Double, Char, Boolean, String, Guid [seem to be supported](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c5#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/AlternativeFrame/AlternativeFrame.cs)) since otherwise you won't be able to use the built-in state saving mechanism of the `Frame` control when you want to save the state when the app gets deactivated and you call [Frame.GetNavigationState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.getnavigationstate.aspx) to save it (`LayoutAwarePage` does it).

Answer (score 2):

The construtor of PageA is the first method to be fired

```
 public sealed partial class PageA : App1.Common.LayoutAwarePage
 {
    public PageA()
    {
        //this is the first code to be fired
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Theo Kouzelis, constructer is the first method which gets fired.
Then comes onNavigatedTo();

However if you wish to perform some tasks on pageA depending on what was the result on pageB you will have to create a static object where you save the value.